# Chrome/Chromium keeps showing "Your connection was interrupted"

Tags: networking, google-chrome, chromium

About once a minute (sometimes more, sometimes less), both Chrome and Chromium show "Your connection was interrupted". Sometimes it just doesn't load and shows a blank screen. On JS heavy pages, ajax requests also fail leading to strange behaviour. The issue is not present in Firefox or on the command line.

I have tried:

- re-installing chrome and chromium
- purging network manager and re-installing
- updating ubuntu to 21.10

since re-installing chrome doesn't fix the issue, I feel that it's somehow related to ubuntu system settings, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that points to network issues?

Comment: Yes, something that points to openvpn it seems, unsure if it's related. I tried commenting out a line as per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/891810/openvpn-wont-start-as-a-service-with-config-file):  and restarting openvpn, but it still happens. The logs are here: https://pastebin.com/na8FnV3M

Comment: I found it! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88667/openvpn-socket-bind-failed-on-local-address-af-inet-ip1194-cannot-assign-r solved the issue for me. Thanks @matigo!